# windows phone 8 geometry transform slow performence

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, rendering, transform

I have two paths,where one is populated by GeometryGroup which contain many LineGeometries and second path with PathGeometry constructed by LineSegment. For both of geometries (GeometryGroup and PathGeometry) i am applied transformGroup, which is animated. I have issue with performence, specially with GeometryGroup. 300 lines gives me around 30 fps. PathGeometry with 300 linesegment gives me around 55 fps. Why GeometryGroup is so much slower? Im using it to construct a grid of lines. Someone can explain it to me?

Generally, what is the best approach to draw in WP8 many animated geometries?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be faster and you are expecting the GeometryGroup not to be modified anymore. Try calling the Freeze() method.

A good reference, [Should I use Geometry.Freeze here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191174/should-i-use-geometry-freeze-here)

That will give you faster performance given that the object is now immutable.

Comment: I'am afraid that WP8 geoemetry doesn't have Freeze() method. And im expecting geometryGroup to be modified - every frame im animating Transform property.